# Jmeter JMESPath Extract and converting to an Array

Tags: arrays, api, jmeter, response, jmespath

Hi is there's a way I can simulate this scenario using JSONPath? Example I have multiple City value and I want all to extract and put it on an Array. Your response is highly appreciated. Thank you so much.

[
{
"id": "MAIN",
"key": 1
},
{
"city": "Roselle",
"id": "87",
"state": "IL",
"key": 1000
},
{
"city": "Chicago",
"id": "7102",
"state": "IL",
"key": 110
},
{
"city": "Crown Point",
"id": "7106",
"state": "IN",
"key": 110038
}
]

Screenshot:

[image]

Expected Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   vars.put('cities', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).findResults{entry -> entry.city}).toPrettyString())
   ```
3. Refer generated value as `${cities}` where required

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Answer (score -1):

Here is one solution.
You can extract the cities from the JSON response using [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) or [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) post processors.

[image]

Your data will be extracted into a set of variables.

Add a JSR223 Post Processor just below the JSON Path Extractor and assign the cities to an array. You can share the array with other following samplers with `vars.put('cities',lstCities)`

```
int cityCount=vars.get("cities_matchNr").toInteger()
def lstCities =[]

for(i in 1..cityCount){
    lstCities.add(vars.get("cities_" + i))
}
vars.putObject("cities", lstCities)
```

The following will demonstrate using the array from the subsequent JSR223 component.

```
def lstCities=vars.getObject("cities") as String[]
log.info("Number of cities ${lstCities.size()}")

for(i in 0..<lstCities.size()) {
    log.info("City $i is ${lstCities[i]}")
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Another solution with [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)

Add a [JSR223 Postprocessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) to the request and add the following code to extract the cities into an array.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

String strResponse=prev.getResponseDataAsString()
log.info("responseJSON ${strResponse}")

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def jsonResponse = jsonSlurper.parseText(strResponse)
def lstCities=jsonResponse.city
lstCities.removeAll([null])

log.info("Cities ${lstCities.size()}")
for(i in 0..<lstCities.size()){
    log.info("City ${i.next()} is ${lstCities[i]} ")
}
```